# I am not able to connect to wifi network

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom

I had tried every code every idea every thing but I failed wireless driver Broadcom `BCM43412`, but when I checked `pci-id` it show not supported. my pci id is `14e4:4365` and chip id is `BCM43142`. I tried edit connection myself to also but I can't what to put in clone mac address place? device mac address is the router mac adress but what is clone mac address? I had placed my laptop mac address in place of clone mac address but it doesn't work. tried every thing but it not work checked additional driver by going system settings it doesn't contain any drivers, tried internet by cable then it connects then how should I correct this? my ubuntu version is 13.10

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please edit your post for correct spelling, and try to make it easier to read.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? just run `cat /etc/lsb-release
` in terminal (press Ctrl+Alt+T) and pot the output in question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

Ok lets follow this steps:
Firt Upgrade your Ubuntu 13.10 to New release version because it's reached end of life on `27 January 2014` , follow [official Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TrustyUpgrades)

If you have previously installed the `bcmwl-kernel-source package`, you will need to remove it by using the purge method:

`sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source`

Run folow line to preparing the system to install and also to update the Ubuntu list of PCI.IDs:

`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo update-pciids`

Then install your wierless driver with following line:

`sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`

and then reboot

`sudo reboot`

I hope this helps

Comment: ohk after trying this method i will tell you what happened ohk be in touch

Comment: i used this code but it is showing this "sudo:apt:command not found" what now i think bcmwl pakage is not installed in my system

Comment: @BrokenHeart I have updated my answer.

Comment: ohk i am updating it but after that if the problenm remains i will know you be in touch

Answer (score 0):

**Try to Upgrade your Ubuntu 13.10(Saucy Salamander) to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. As it has reaches to EOL(End of Life) on July 17 2014.**

Comment: HOW I CAN UPDATE IT TELL ME